# Humans accidentally travel to medieval planet with two alien factions

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a sci-fi book where humans accidentally space travel to a medieval-technology world where there are two alien factions.

I remember correctly, the aliens are physically taller than the humans, but otherwise the same, and one faction inhabits the cold north, led by a male, while the other faction, led by a female, inhabits the desert south. Humans decide to help the north faction.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info

Comment: So, by "Medieval", are you talking about technology levels? Societal structures? Knights and archers and chivalry? Is it something that seems to be explicitly "human Medieval" versus just a general feel?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yes. the aliens have medieval technology. I think they may have a fuedal society but not sure

Comment: Was there anything that distinguished alien society from Terran society other than them being taller? No telepathy, poison fangs, extra arms, different sense, different physics, or magic?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No different things as far as I can tell. I read a quarter of the book at Sam's Club a long time ago but had to leave.

Comment: the south is led by a woman and the north by a man. the south is winning.

Comment: I went ahead and edited those details into your question.

Comment: Do the authors CJ Cherryh or Jack Vance ring a bell?

Comment: I know of them but they didn't write this book